# nginx gateway timeout after 1minutes 20 seconds

Tags: nginx, timeout

My nginx settings are like this :

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name websitenamne.in www.websitename.in;

    root /root/path;

    location /static {
    }

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8003/;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
    send_timeout 3600;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}

# what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
error_page 500 502 503 504 /static/50x.html;
}
```

In the above , at location /, I added these things :

```
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
    send_timeout 3600;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
```

But still nginx sending Gateway timeout error . How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not possible to set connect timeout longer than a time your OS will re-try SYN packet transmissions, usually 75 seconds as indicated in [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_connect_timeout).